# Accordion CSS before and after usage

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have written code for an accordion, with a total of 5 panels (will be showing just 1 here)

Problem is, when the page loads, the panel title buttons are automatically highlighted as green. When I click on them, it opens the section smoothly, and all details can be read and closed. But only after I do this once will my buttons return to normal (The panel title gets the + sign with a gray background, which on hovering shows green). Why is it that it's not like this in the first place when the page loads?

[fiddle with code](https://jsfiddle.net/eenbdhkz/3/)

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
   <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
    <!--panel 1-->
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a class="" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse">
            Committee 1 Details
            </a>
           </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
        <div class="panel-body">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque lacinia lacinia mauris, at ultricies leo ornare nec. Vivamus eu est vel felis dignissim tempor. Nulla facilisi. Duis molestie tortor ac tempor volutpat. Phasellus nec mi aliquet, sollicitudin
          neque eget, consectetur libero. Vestibulum sollicitudin sapien libero, egestas tempus eros scelerisque eu.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

```
#accordion .panel-title a:after, #accordion .panel-title   a.collapsed:after {
content: "\f068";
font-family: FontAwesome;
font-size: 15px;
color: #fff;
width: 45px;
height: 100%;
line-height: 54px;
text-align: center;
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
left: -1px;
background: #3DC9B3;
transition: all .2s;
}
#accordion .panel-title a.collapsed:after {
content: "\f067";
color: #959595;
background: #f4f4f4;
transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "normal" CSS  you're describing is based off of the class `.collapsed`. That class is only applied after you collapse an accordion item. To have it display that way initially on page load, add the `.collapsed` class to the element's HTML.

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
   <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
    <!--panel 1-->
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse">
            Committee 1 Details
            </a>
           </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
        <div class="panel-body">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque lacinia lacinia mauris, at ultricies leo ornare nec. Vivamus eu est vel felis dignissim tempor. Nulla facilisi. Duis molestie tortor ac tempor volutpat. Phasellus nec mi aliquet, sollicitudin
          neque eget, consectetur libero. Vestibulum sollicitudin sapien libero, egestas tempus eros scelerisque eu.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/eenbdhkz/5/